# PHP Authorization: Auto Login, Bypass User Login

Tags: php, authorization

(For these purposes, "private" = no web access)

So, there's this thing where if a PHP script is accessing private files, you have to put in an authorization header.  All the advice goes like this:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"My Realm\"");
        Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        echo "Text to send if user hits Cancel button\n";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

But I don't want to do that, making the user enter MY username and password.  I want the PHP to parse private files into a non-private word count that anyone can see when they go to my site.  This particular PHP file is not private.  I want to be able to log into any computer and get this word count.  So obviously, I need to automatically set the username and password.

How do I bypass the user authorization request and automatically fill in the Username and Password for access just this file?

Comment: Oh that's hilarious.  After searching at least 10~20 more articles.  (None of them worked), I thought I had finally found the jackpot (Google link to stackoverflow question).  The question was worded just right.  I couldn't figure out how I had missed it before.  As it turns out, it brought me back here.  *facepalm*